# configure: error: GSL CBLAS library not found

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, configure, gsl

I have installed GSL using `sudo apt-get install gsl-bin` as I am trying to install a package (http://seeslab.info/downloads/network-c-libraries-rgraph/ ) which requires the GNU Scientific Libraries (GSL). However when I run `./configure` for said package I get the error message `configure: error: GSL CBLAS library not found`. Why might that be?

Comment: You probably require the related "dev-"package. Perhaps `gsl-dev` or similar?

Comment: Correct. `gsl-bin` just installs example binaries and the runtime library it depends upon.  This is also a duplicate question.

Comment: That does indeed seem to have solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must install libgsl-dev with the command below

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

I hope that it solve your problem!

Comment: Note that if you are on Red Hat/CENTOS the command is `sudo yum install gsl-devel`.